# How can I transfer values from object 2 to object 1 if the key is present in object 1

Tags: typescript

I recieve some data from the database and I want to format it in a certain way. But when trying to format it, I ran into some difficulties. How would I handle this senario where I use enums as the keys of the base object. Then go over the the second object and grab the values if the key matches a key of object 1 and and then place them in object 1.

The idea is to have some sort of base object that already has default values. I use a enum as key because I want the object to change whenever I change the enum. But I get some errors.

```
enum test {
    empty = '',
    first = 'a',
    second = 'b',
    third = 'c'
}

type defaultObject = {
    [test.first]: string,
    [test.second]: string,
    [test.third]: string
}

const myObject = {
    [test.first]: 'notImportant',
    [test.second]: 'notImportant',
    [test.third]: 'notImportant'
} as defaultObject;

const someFetchedObject = {
    a: 'notImportant2',
    b: 'notImportant2',
}

for (let key in someFetchedObject)
    if (key in myObject) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(myObject[key]); //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }'.
        console.log(someFetchedObject[key]); //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; }'
        myObject[key] = someFetchedObject[key]; // This is what I want to do
    }

//console.log(myObject);
// Should output {a:'notImportant2', b:'notImportant2', c:'notImportant'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is inferring the type of `key` as `string`.

So `myObject[key]` is an error, because `myObject` cannot be indexed by `string`. the literal `'a'` or `'b'` is required.

Instead you want it to infer `key` to be of type `keyof typeof someFetchedObject`.

This happens because (most of the time) when you iterate over keys in typescript it may have other keys that are not part of the interface. However, in this case, you can be sure that only the keys you want are present, so you can use a cast.

```
for (let key of Object.keys(someFetchedObject) as (keyof typeof someFetchedObject)[]) {
  //...
}
```

We use `Object.keys` to get an array of property names that we can then cast. It's normally `string[]`, but we can cast it an array of keys from `someObject`. Note that I also changed the loop to `for of` instead of `for in` since we are iterating over an array now.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/KYOwrgtgBALsDOMoG8BQUNWBADjAnlALxQDkpANOpgGYCWATosWQIaXUbzADGA9iAAmLUgCMOmWAAtGwkqR6lUAX1SoCOYFEHAarMABsYAeVEArXkhJpJAbTiIAdPSYwAugC4oiBnRABzKjsHGEdufiFPbxhfAKDMewRQmBkGQSifP38VNQjmCHxTCx4rFE4oRKcXRCjSED4YAElcPgYYVhAYCQSQsN4BdK86huacVvbO7oxK5NTBsnqmlraOrpUoVnhtXX0jIssAblyBZng+CGAAMWAYHilgQX2SlhtMViHF0fHVgCYpqFEHxGywmMD+VFUqBorSgAAoDDcoABrYCEPg0KBPUIo-DwWFnC7XW73R7mSwASg2W1hOPRsHwmjpBKuNzuDyx5NsbnJ5ToGJpqKgfigBQ5ZUkkjyfARjgMfH8Avw5KOEswUplcoVorJJVsOO5BygAHojQBRBEXTpC3AGOg8OgwAyEKSbDYgNggfCkemaAG8fTcLAADxwDAQ8DoAigdI0WlImQC3p4HVISFEWjA3GEMD4QqEwCDPrjyA2XgT-kNgOisQrUB4ZZiWUNylIjnKkpO0uAsvl+POLOJ7J1MD1qINxrNFtASDoNrtDqdUBdWw6Hq9Rb9yczWgLofDkfdMYZcfLSZTaYzWdgub8OkLsbIJfe1abAIbNebSlVGG1xRH+pYZkiTZUk-1HfA3ENE0oAAFRkLY6C2AB3F0kEaKAkNWa9tD4cpIXVbtNVhX8KSOaCAGUpD4QxhGomAcDAJBkHeYYljGFZOnBN9WK+DiwUoOsPB4kFVlIZQgA)